# box-plot not working with factor data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a simple boxplot of some survey data.

**Data**
The data is survey data, and each row has a response recorded 1-5.

```
**Example Data**

Race= 2,2,3,2,5
Rating = 1,1,3,5,5
```

Converting to factors

```
df$Race = factor(DF$Race)
df$Rating = factor(DF$Rating)
```

Assigning each factor variable levels

```
levels(df$Race) = c("Asian/Pacific Islander", "White" , "American Indian/Eskimo", "Black/African American", "Other","NA")
levels(df$Rating) = c("Poor","Below Avg.","Neutral","Good","Excellent", "NA")

ggplot(df, aes(x=Race, y=Rating)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Using the full data I get a result like this. 
[image: GGPLOT output]
Please let me know why this turns out funky. Also, How can I remove NA's?. I'm brand new to R. So if you see something else that I am doing wrong, or poorly please let me know! Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Using @jlhoward code provided in the comments I can generate the following - but it's plotting them all the same, and not plotting "white."

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Race, y=as.numeric(Rating))) + geom_boxplot() +scale_y_continuous(labels=df$Rating,breaks=as.integer(df$Rating))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the factor levels ("Poor", "Below Avg" etc.) to appear on the Y axis, but you actually want the "rating" boxplot to be computed with numerical values. Is that correct?

If that is the case, you would need to **not** convert your "rating" variable into a factor before feeding them to ggplot (leave it numerical), and then simply label the y axis appropriately according to your factor levels.

(A reproducible example would help answer the question more fully).

Comment: You are right. However, I need the data in factor form for ggplot barplots I've put together. Why doesn't the following work?

    ggplot(df, aes(x=Race, y=as.numeric(Rating)) + geom_boxplot()

Comment: It does work - `ggplot(df, aes(x=Race, y=as.numeric(Rating))) + geom_boxplot() +scale_y_continuous(labels=df$Rating,breaks=as.integer(df$Rating))`

Comment: @jhoward I've updated my original question with what your code produces. It's close, but no cigar.